# What is the meaning of the number displayed by echo $$?

Tags: shell

By accident I typed `echo $$` into the command line, but instead of an error message I got a 5-digit number. I repeated `echo $$` on different terminals and each time I got a 5-digit number. What is the meaning of `$$` and the number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the process id of the current shell.

[Source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02):

> Expands to the decimal process ID of the invoked shell. In a subshell (see Shell Execution Environment ), '$' shall expand to the same value as that of the current shell.

Answer (score 9):

#### $$

> The PID of the current process.

More examples of different uses listed below:

---

#### $_

> The default parameter for a lot of functions.

#### $.

> Holds the current record or line number of the file handle that was
>   last read. It is read-only and will be reset to 0 when the file handle
>   is closed.

#### $/

> Holds the input record separator. The record separator is usually the
>   newline character. However, if $/ is set to an empty string, two or
>   more newlines in the input file will be treated as one.

#### $,

> The output separator for the print() function. Nor-mally, this
>   variable is an empty string. However, setting $, to a newline might be
>   useful if you need to print each element in the parameter list on a
>   separate line.

#### $\

> Added as an invisible last element to the parameters passed to the
>   print() function. Normally, an empty string, but if you want to add a
>   newline or some other suffix to everything that is printed, you can
>   assign the suffix to $.

#### $

> The default format for printed numbers. Normally, it's set to %.20g,
>   but you can use the format specifiers covered in the section "Example:
>   Printing Revisited" in Chapter 9to specify your own default format.

#### $%

> Holds the current page number for the default file handle. If you use
>   select() to change the default file handle, $% will change to reflect
>   the page number of the newly selected file handle.

#### $=

> Holds the current page length for the default file handle. Changing
>   the default file handle will change $= to reflect the page length of
>   the new file handle.

#### $-

> Holds the number of lines left to print for the default file handle.
>   Changing the default file handle will change $- to reflect the number
>   of lines left to print for the new file handle.

#### $~

> Holds the name of the default line format for the default file handle.
>   Normally, it is equal to the file handle's name.

#### $^

> Holds the name of the default heading format for the default file
>   handle. Normally, it is equal to the file handle's name with _TOP
>   appended to it.

#### $|

> If nonzero, will flush the output buffer after every write() or
>   print() function. Normally, it is set to 0.

#### $?

> Holds the status of the last pipe close, back-quote string, or
>   system() function.

#### $&

> Holds the string that was matched by the last successful pattern
>   match.

#### $`

> Holds the string that preceded whatever was matched by the last
>   successful pattern match.

#### $'

> Holds the string that followed whatever was matched by the last
>   successful pattern match.

#### $+

> Holds the string matched by the last bracket in the last successful
>   pattern match. For example, the statement /Fieldname: (.*)|Fldname:
>   (.*)/ && ($fName = $+); will find the name of a field even if you
>   don't know which of the two possible spellings will be used.

#### $*

> Changes the interpretation of the ^ and $ pattern anchors. Setting $*
>   to 1 is the same as using the /m option with the regular expression
>   matching and substitution operators. Normally, $* is equal to 0.

#### $0

> Holds the name of the file containing the Perl script being executed.

#### $

> This group of variables ($1, $2, $3, and so on) holds the regular
>   expression pattern memory. Each set of parentheses in a pattern stores
>   the string that match the components surrounded by the parentheses
>   into one of the $ variables.

#### $[

> Holds the base array index. Normally, it's set to 0. Most Perl authors
>   recommend against changing it without a very good reason.

#### $]

> Holds a string that identifies which version of Perl you are using.
>   When used in a numeric context, it will be equal to the version number
>   plus the patch level divided by 1000.

#### $"

> This is the separator used between list elements when an array
>   variable is interpolated into a double-quoted string. Normally, its
>   value is a space character.

#### $;

> Holds the subscript separator for multidimensional array emulation.
>   Its use is beyond the scope of this book.

#### $!

> When used in a numeric context, holds the current value of errno. If
>   used in a string context, will hold the error string associated with
>   errno.

#### $@

> Holds the syntax error message, if any, from the last eval() function
>   call.

#### $<

> This UNIX-based variable holds the read uid of the current process.

#### $>

> This UNIX-based variable holds the effective uid of the current
>   process.

#### $)

> This UNIX-based variable holds the read gid of the current process. If
>   the process belongs to multiple groups, then $) will hold a string
>   consisting of the group names separated by spaces.

#### $:

> Holds a string that consists of the characters that can be used to end
>   a word when word-wrapping is performed by the ^ report formatting
>   character. Normally, the string consists of the space, newline, and
>   dash characters.

#### $^D

> Holds the current value of the debugging flags. For more information.

#### $^F

> Holds the value of the maximum system file description. Normally, it's
>   set to 2. The use of this variable is beyond the scope of this book.

#### $^I

> Holds the file extension used to create a backup file for the in-place
>   editing specified by the -i command line option. For example, it could
>   be equal to ".bak."

#### $^L

> Holds the string used to eject a page for report printing.

#### $^P

> This variable is an internal flag that the debugger clears so it will
>   not debug itself.

#### $^T

> Holds the time, in seconds, at which the script begins running.

#### $^W

> Holds the current value of the -w command line option.

#### $^X

> Holds the full pathname of the Perl interpreter being used to run the
>   current script.

Source:

- http://www.unix.com/302219737-post3.html